# How to pack multiple parameter into one

Tags: ruby, prawn

I use the Prawn to generate pdf. To make a `table`, I do:

```
table test_rows(test), :column_widths => [100, 200, 360] , &table_style
```

Is there any way that can let me put a proc into `table_style`? I don't want to repeat `column_widths` and `table_style` in my code.

```
def table_style
  return Proc.new{
    row(0).font_style = :bold
    columns(1..3).align = :center    
    self.row_colors = ["DDDDDD", "FFFFFF"]
    self.header = true      
  }
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*Is there any way can let me put into table_style proc ?*"

Answer (score 0):

This method appears to take three arguments: data, options and a block. See https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/table.rb

If you are trying to store those arguments as temporary variables to re-use in other calls to table, you can use something like:

```
options = { :column_widths => [100, 200, 360] }
table_style = Proc.new { ... }

table(data1, options, &table_style)
table(data2, options, &table_style)
```